# EMFILE: too many open files, open - WriteFileSync

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an EMFILE error which I believe is caused by WriteFileSync? I am writing tens of thousands of JSON files and I blow through the file limit. How can I tweak the code to fix the issue?

```
const writeMetaData = (_data) => {


fs.writeFileSync("./output/_metadata.json", _data);

};
```

Then

```
writeMetaData(JSON.stringify(metadataList));
```